# AR9287 Wifi authentification required

Tags: wireless, sony

You are my last hope. I wanted to change my os to Ubuntu 15.04. Everything seemed ok, but my wifi module Artheros ar9287 thinks, that my wifi password is wrong and I get stuck on "authentification required" window.
But the password is good, it is encrypted by wpa2 personal and it is Wireless-G. Windows 8 connects without problems. Anybody help(

Comment: Did you try re-entering it? Another stupid question: is Capslock on?

Comment: yeah, I checked it for many times. It is ok, fedora works without problem with this artheros, ubuntu 12.04 also worked fine

Comment: See if you can forget the network in Network Settings.

Comment: I deleted it and tried again to connect, not succeed in

Comment: Have you rebooted the access point?

Comment: okay, give me a second)

Comment: Rebooted, still same issue

Comment: does smbdy have any ideas?

Comment: Try removing the card in Network Settings ans then rebooting to reinstall it.

Comment: sorry, but how to do it(the button minus is forbidden to click)

Comment: There should be an Unlock button in the top right of the window

Comment: there is only airplane mode button i just turned it off and rebooted and turned on

Comment: See if it's anywhere else.

Comment: it didn't work (

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/rAWf8qf.png

Comment: OK. Use a terminal and run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down`, reboot and then run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`.

Comment: still access error. it seems to be a driver error

Comment: but how to fix it

Comment: `sudo modprobe wlan0`

Comment: andrjuha01@andrjuha01-VPCF11C5E:~$ sudo modprobe wlan0
modprobe: FATAL: Module wlan0 not found.
Seems weird

Comment: `sudo modprobe wl`?

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.

Comment: `xinput list` and put the output here.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/K3N69ZW.png

Comment: Sorry, `lsusb`.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/PV6CRHd.png

Comment: `lspci`, maybe?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/BeYG0cG.png

Comment: OK. I need to go now, but I do see the card now.

Comment: okay, hope I'll see your other ideas here tomorrow)
Thanx for your time)

Answer (score 1):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us know how it's working.